# powershell command to close windows explorer window based on selection

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute a powershell command using my program to close windows explorer window based on selection. It seems to be executed correctly, but the window does not close. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Here is the command: to close windows explorer window which selected C drive.

```
powershell.exe  (((((New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()) ^| Where-Object { $_.LocationURL -like '$(([uri]"C:\").AbsoluteUri)*' }))  ^| ForEach-Object { $_.Quit() })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
$ShellApplication = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$ShellApplication.Windows() | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "File Explorer" -and $_.LocationURL -match "General_logs" } | ForeEach-Object{ $_.Quit() }
```

Obviously you'll need to change what you're matching.  I haven't messed with it much, we can probably make this more eloquent.  Let me know how it goes.

In One line:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows() | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "File Explorer" -and $_.LocationURL -match "General_logs" } | ForEach-Object{ $_.Quit() }
```

Now if you want to run from PowerShell.exe :

```
powershell -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command .{ (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows() | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'File Explorer' -and $_.LocationURL -match 'General_logs' } | ForEach-Object{ $_.Quit() } }
```

This worked for me but note I had to change the quoting.  It's a bad habit of mine to double quote when it isn't needed.  I also added -WindowStyle Hidden so you don't get the flash of the console and -NoProfile, so you don't have to wait for the profile script to run...

Comment: Steven, thanks for your quick response. 

Basically, I want to execute this command with my java program as a single line command using powershell.exe. the additional details are, when we connect a device using a usb drive, it is opening a new window which I need to close so that it does not overlay on my app. I know which drive the usb drive gets and can pass dynamically. 
The command which I posted above was tried in command prompt window.

Comment: When I tried to execute the above command as single line, I get these errors:

C:\>powershell.exe ((New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows() ^| Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "File Explorer" -and $_.LocationURL -match "C:" } ^| ForeEach-Object{ $_.Quit() })

Comment: At line:1 char:80
+ ... bject Shell.Application).Windows() | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq File Ex ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-eq' operator.
At line:1 char:81
+ ...  Shell.Application).Windows() | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq File Explore ...
+                                                              ~~~~
Unexpected token 'File' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Comment: Does it have to be on a single line?

Comment: That explains some of your earlier formatting.  I edited the main answer, I think I've got it working.  Probably not the only syntax, but let me know how it goes with this...

Comment: Steven

your first command (In one line) works fine with my java program. 

Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: That's awesome.  If you get a chance can you mark answered?